# How button name as Backspace work as Backspace for multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

On keyboard button name as BackSpace do not work as backspace for multiple textBoxes.

for single textbox i write this code and successfully .

```
textbox.text = textbox.Text.Remove(textbox.Textlength-1,1);
```

but not work for multiple textboxes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by multiple textboxes, but have a look at [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You have to know which TextBox had the focus *before* the user clicked the button.  Use their Enter event to update a variable named, say, LastTextBox.  If this is supposed to be a touch-screen interface then consider popping up the keyboard when the user clicks the text box.

Comment: Consider making your screen keyboard [non-focusable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iinputelement.focusable.aspx), so you can check for the focused element on button click. This is somewhat reasonable, since button focus is mainly used for keyboard navigation and keyboard-navigating in a screen keyboard should not be required.

Comment: its a touch screen key and i want to remove text with backspace button . and this made in windows form application  .

Comment: Oh sorry, overlooked the winforms tag. Guess my answer doesn't really apply there^^ Maybe winforms has similar properties for focus management?

Comment: backspace button work for single textbox is                                 txtname.text = txtname.Text.Remove(txtname.Textlength-1,1)               and this work correctly. kindly tell me for multiple textboxes

Comment: If the keyboard works normally for entering text, then it should work for the backspace as well. What are you doing differently in this case?

Comment: object obj;
private void btnQ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                (obj as TextBox).Text += btnQ.Text;
            }
        }

Comment: private void btnBackSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtCategory.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                txtCategory.Text = txtCategory.Text.Remove(txtCategory.Text.Length - 1, 1);
            }
        }
this work correctly for single textbox not multiple and i want for multiple as shown in pic

Comment: Please edit the code into your question and format it appropriately. Also, notice the difference between `obj as TextBox` and `txtCategory`?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit** Note that this is an WPF answer but the question is about winforms. I'll leave the answer for now in case someone looks for the same thing with WPF.

You can use the `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` property:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="tbElements" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
        <TextBox x:Name="tb1" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tb2" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Test" Margin="3" Height="26" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Then the textboxes are managed in a separate logical focus scope

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var test1 = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
        var test2 = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(tbElements);
    }
```

The result will be, that `test1` references the clicked button, because it has the current focus, but `test2` references the last focused textbox, because it has the local focus within its separate logical focus scope.

An alternative would be to set the `Button` property `Focusable` to `False`, so if a textbox has the focus when the button is clicked, the focus stays within the textbox. This prevents keyboard navigation to the button but since the button is part of the screen keyboard, this may be acceptable or even desired behavior.

Comment: hi ..grek40.. when i focus on barcode textbox then backspace work for barcode. and when i focus on name then backspace do not work .....

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan Its important to determine the active textbox dynamically, not just using the variable of one specific textbox element. This is why I use the focus manager in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that OP does not want to perform backspaces on multiple textboxes, rather wants Backspace button to affect textbox currently focused, so:

To emulate a keyboard stroke use [SendKeys.Send(string keys)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of current implementation. This will perform `BACKSPACE` on control which has focus:

```
private void backspace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //{BACKSPACE}, {BS}, or {BKSP}
    SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}");
}
```